# Ubuntu 16.0.4 hangs on boot with blinking cursor, lvmetad not active, boot-repair and fsck don't work

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair

Had used auto-remove to remove boostlib (1.58) libraries from my system, removed the old shared boost libraries from my /usr/lib/x86... folder then built and installed boostlib 1.63 from source. This lead to many programs not running due to missing links shared libraries from the recently uninstalled boostlib 1.58.

One program hung, and I restarted the system at which point this message flashed briefly before just staying indefinitely at the famous black screen with a blinking cursor.

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: recovering journal
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 3690696/30105600 files, 99487076/120399872 blocks
```

I tried:

1. Using boot-repair via a Live Disk to repair grub, and went through the whole process, it did not change anything.
2. Booting to an earlier kernel, it did not work.
3. Via recovery, using fsck - it hangs after "[OK] Reached Target Swap"
4. Via recovery, dpkg to repair any broken packages, it tried to update 14 libraries but failed to connect though it's connected through ethernet.
   "Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'" for all packages it tried to grab.
5. Via recovery, failsafeX in case it's a gfx issue - didn't work.

Any specific suggestions would be appreciated, have gone through the "blinking cursor" related links with not much luck.

boot-repair summary pastebin https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QbBQTCj889/

Comment: Can you post the output by dpkg ?

Comment: Added the error message I see for all packages, unfortunately can't transcribe all the text and packages. Seems to be some DNS issue, and am trying to run dpkg through live CD.